# How to trigger an integer conversion warning when passing an enum instead of a pointer

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

Given the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum{
    ISP_INPUT_NONE,
    ISP_INPUT_DOLBY
} UserStream_t;

int someFunc(const char * str) {
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** arg)
{
    int a = ISP_INPUT_NONE;
    someFunc(ISP_INPUT_NONE);
    someFunc(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The second call triggers an integer conversion warning, but the first doesn't.

```
gcc -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:17:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘someFunc’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   17 |     someFunc(a);
      |              ^
      |              |
      |              int
test.c:8:27: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    8 | int someFunc(const char * str) {
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Are enum silently converted to pointers?

I thought C enums were considered as integers. I would like the first call to generate the same warning as the second.

Comment: "The first call triggers an integer conversion warning, but the second doesn't." According to what you posted, it is the second call (the one using an integer variable) that is triggering the warning and the first (using an enum value literally) that passes silently. Was this a typo?

Comment: Now try with `ISP_INPUT_DOLBY` :D . `ISP_INPUT_NONE` is `0`, so it's implicitly converted to `void*`.

Comment: So zero valued enum are silently considered as NULL pointer, but zero valued int is not ?

Comment: @shodanex: An enumeration constant is an `int`. Both an enumeration constant with value zero and the integer constant `0` qualify as a null pointer constant. (This, “null pointer constant,” is the proper term. `NULL` is the name of a macro.)

Comment: GCC 10.2 appears unable to warn about this. Clang 11.0 does, with `-Wnon-literal-null-conversion`, which is on by default. You should specify the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are enum silently converted to pointers ?

Well, some of them. `ISP_INPUT_NONE` is `0` and enumeration values are [constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) and a constant expression with the value `0` **is** [a null pointer](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) constant. And converting a null pointer constant to another pointer is just normal.

The warning will still be issued if the `enum` value is not `0`, for example for `someFunc(ISP_INPUT_DOLBY);`.

> How to trigger integer conversion warning when passing enum instead of pointer

Ideas:

Start `enum` with 1 instead of 0.

```
typedef enum {
    ISP_INPUT_NONE = 1,
    ISP_INPUT_DOLBY
} UserStream_t;
```

Use a structure and have conversion errors.

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned char val;
} UserStream_t;
static const UserStream_t ISP_INPUT_NONE = {0};
static const UserStream_t ISP_INPUT_DOLBY = {1};
```

Some way use a macro so that `ISP_INPUT_NONE` is not a constant expression.

```
static int entity(int a) { return a; }

typedef enum{
    ISP_INPUT_NONE,
#define ISP_INPUT_NONE (entity(ISP_INPUT_NONE))
    ISP_INPUT_DOLBY
} UserStream_t;
```

Use `clang` compiler with `-Wnon-literal-null-conversion` option.

In g++ there is `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant` option, but no such option for C in gcc. You could also make a feature request to gcc.

Comment: The fact that `ISP_INPUT_NONE` is a null pointer constant does not mean a compiler cannot issue a diagnostic message for its use as a pointer. Clang does.

Comment: Re “a constant expression with the value `0` just is a null pointer by itself”: Not quite. It is a *null pointer constant*. If `0` were a null pointer, `int x = 0;` would be invalid, as the initializer for an `int` cannot be a pointer. A null pointer constant is not a pointer; it is a type of constant that can be accepted in certain places where a pointer is otherwise required.